# How to extend MouseEventHandler function

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, eventhandler, extending

first, I would like to apologize for my lack of knowledge, but I am new in C# and I am missing some basic principles.

**Here is my current scenario:**
In my scenario I create something like chess desk of `pictureboxes`. They are placed inside of control "Panel" in *Winform* form - panel is **scrollable**! 
Each picture box has unique name like `pbR1_C1` generated in constructor.

*R - stands for Row on desk*

*C - Stands for Column on desk*

All is made during runtime since the chess desk size is loaded after program starts. Used objects look like this:

```
/* Simple preview of object with public variables - just for preview  */

public class ptFcElement                    
{
    public string stName;                   /* "pbR1_C1", "pbR1_C2" */
    public int iRow;                        /* 1                    */
    public int iColumn;                     /* 4                    */
    public PictureBox pbPictureBox;         /* using System.Drawing;*/                                          

    public ptFcElement()                                                               
    {
        stName = sGenerateName();
    }

}
```

Then I assign event handler for each picture box

```
ptFcElementTemp.pbPictureBox.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(MouseButton_Click);
```

At this point I am able to identify that I have pressed some picture box, but I don't know which one.

**Here is the question:**
Since panel is scrollable - I can not simple identify pressed picture box - it always calls the same function.

```
void MouseButton_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Do some stuff....
    //In case panel is not scrollable, 
    //I can identify pressed picture box by coordinates of mouse click.  
    //But if panel is scrollable, I am screwed.
}
```

**Desired idea:**

Is there any possibility to extend `MouseEventHandler` event function? I know that simple classes are easily to extend, but I am not sure how to work with event functions.

```
ptFcElementTemp.pbPictureBox.MouseClick += 
        new MouseEventHandler(MouseButton_Click, "pbR1_C1");

void MouseButton_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e, string sUniqueName)
{
    //Here I am able to identify pressed bisturebox by sUniqueName
     if (sUniqueName == "pbR1_C1")
     {
         //do something
     }

     if (sUniqueName == "pbR2_C3")
     {
         //do something different
     }
}
```

Thank you, see you. 
And please, explain it as easy as possible, for dummy. :-)

Comment: I just edited my answer to show you how to integrate the event into your own class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it like this:

```
void MouseButton_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var pb = sender as PictureBox;
    if(pb!=null){
        //Do something with the instance the PictureBox which fired the event
    }
}
```

After discussion with Yacoub Massad I want to suggest you following enhancement:

Declare your own event, which you fire when the PictureBox is clicked.

```
public class ptFcElement {
    public string stName;                   /* "pbR1_C1", "pbR1_C2" */
    public int iRow;                        /* 1                    */
    public int iColumn;                     /* 4                    */
    public PictureBox pbPictureBox;         /* using System.Drawing;*/

    public event EventHandler PictureBoxWasClicked;
    protected virtual void OnPictureBoxWasClicked(){
        if (this.PictureBoxWasClicked != null)
            this.PictureBoxWasClicked(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    public ptFcElement() {
        stName = sGenerateName();
        this.pbPictureBox.Click += pbPictureBox_Click;
    }

    private void pbPictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.OnPictureBoxWasClicked();
    }

}
```

Outside you can react on this event instead of the PictureBox' Click-event. The "sender" will be the instance of your own class directly.

If you want you could even define an own EventArgs-class to pass what ever parameters you like...

Answer (score 1):

As a direct answer to your question, you can do something like this:

```
ptFcElementTemp.pbPictureBox.MouseClick +=
    (object sndr, MouseEventArgs m_args)
        => MouseButton_Click(sndr, m_args, "pbR1_C1");
```

You can pass whatever parameter that you want.

This is helpful if you want more context than just the `PictureBox` that was clicked since that object can be access using the `sender` parameter. For example, you might want to get access to the corresponding `ptFcElement`.

Comment: This approach is quite hacky... You underrun the principles of events... Anyway there would be better designs. Maybe a derived PictureBox including all other data or a user defined class throwing its own event. What you suggest is somehow - uhm - beautiful in an ugly way :-)

Comment: @Shnugo, you are right :). I am just giving OP a direct answer to the question. I am not sure if we have enough context to suggest a better design.

Comment: So I could use some magic trick called lambda expression. Ok, thank you both, I will try to make it working. :-)

At the moment I am receiving error, because in my example I create object with "new MouseEventHandler(MouseButton_Click)"

In new idea I don't use "new" operator, so I will have to think out something.

Anyway, great thanks for both of you! :-)

Comment: @YacoubMassad, You are rigth, that there is a little to little context... I just edited my answer to suggest a solution with a pass-through event...

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to determine wich control was clicked? I hope that's what you're asking for.
The sender parameter contains your control.
For example:

```
if (sender==ptFcElementTemp.pbPictureBox){
//Do stuff
}
else if(sender==ptFcElementTemp.otherControl){
//Do other stuff
}
```

Comment: No that is not the the point. 
I am trying to identify which one picturebox was clicked. There are tens of pictureboxes and I am not able to determine which one I have clicked.

Comment: Well, a picture box is a control.